# EL is not working in a jsp page

Tags: struts2, jstl, el

I  have a JSP page,In that page,I am trying to use the page scope attributes using jstl and struts2 tags.
 The following piece of code is,

```
      <%@ taglib  uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
      <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

      <c:set var="test" value="ramesh"/>
      <c:set var="test1" value="${test}"/>
      <s:set var="test2" value="${test}" />
```

the `<s:set>` tag yields the following exception " According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions".

I have two questions.

1)`${test}` works when it is used in `<c:set>` tag.

2)`${test}` does not  works when it is used in `<s:set>` tag. Why?

Comment: Because *attribute value does not accept any expressions*.

Comment: @Aleksandr but why <c:set ....>  works.

Comment: Obviously because `<c:set>` accepts expressions.

Comment: @Aleksandr,so <c:set..> accepts expressions and <s:set..> does not accepts expressions right. This is bcoz of developping those tags like that, right?.

Answer (score 1):

EL and JSTL are now in Java EE standards, so they can cooperate well, I think.

However, when in struts 2 tags, because struts 2 have their expression language - OGNL, 
so I think they prefer to use OGNL to EL in their tags, and that is the reason why they do not support EL. These are my guess.

Answer (score 0):

From Apache link

[From Apache FAQ link](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/why-cant-i-use-jstl-style-el-expressions-in-struts-tags.html)

As of Struts version 2.0.9 the JSTL/JSP expression language (EL) has been disabled for Struts tag attributes which evaluate OGNL. This is a precaution against security vulnerabilities that can result from the double-evaluation that occurs when an attribute is first processed as a JSTL/JSP EL expression and then the result is processed as an OGNL expression. The solution is to express all dynamic attribute values in Struts tags using OGNL expressions directly.